# Манипуляции с JTable

Tags: jtable, java

Есть две Frame: на первой находится таблица JTable1, на второй, к примеру, есть несколько JTextField для заполнения и одна JButton1. Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку JButton1 в JTable1 сразу добавлялась новая запись? Перепробовал много чего, но тщетно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вешаешь ActionListener на JButton, который считывает текст из JTextField, дальше свои значения и делаешь repaint() таблицы. Но конечно лучше б было если б ты привёл пример своего кода...

Comment: Какого-то работоспособного кода у меня нет. Поэтому и спрашиваю. Насчет repaint() - но я же не могу напрямую обратиться к таблице.

Comment: @Сергей1991: а как _обычно_ записи попадают в таблицу? (Например, через `TableModel`?) Ну так таким же путём их и надо добавлять из Listener'а.

Comment: @Сергей1991:

1. К таблице обращаться не надо. Добавьте данные в `TableModel`, таблица обновится автоматически.
2. `ActionListener` в нашем случае -- это функция, которая будет вызвана при нажатии на кнопку. В общем случае -- функция, которая будет вызвана при наступлении какого-то условия, для `ActionListener` -- когда какой-то `Action` будет выполнен. (Почитайте про паттерн Observer на досуге.)

Comment: Т.е. в данном случае этим самым Action будет функция addRow?

Comment: @Сергей1991: не, `Action`, за которым наблюдают -- это нажатие на кнопку. А `ActionListener` выполнит `AddRow`, когда наблюдаемый `Action` будет выполнен.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду разбираться...

Comment: Попробовал - ничего не понял. В чем вообще смысл ActionListener, если я просто могу в NetBeans выделить кнопку, нажать правую кнопку мыши и выбрать пункт "События", затем "Action Performed" и т.д.?

Comment: Приведите пример хоть какой-нибудь, в Интернете ничего нету. Или хотя бы ссылку на какой-нибудь ресурс, где об этом толково написано.